# SVG overlay in Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, svg

I am dynamically creating an svg of markers to place over a map at high zoom levels when there are too many markers to actually pin on the map. I have the svg made; how do I overlay it in the Google Maps API? All the documentation I see says I need to create an image with a path but I don't have that. How do I do this?

Comment: I haven't tried anything - I have no idea where to start. I read the docs for a custom overlay (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays) and it says to reference an image with a path. I don't have that with the svg??

Comment: In case you haven't already discovered, a similar feature already exists: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

Answer (score 0):

(late reply for other users with same problem)

If you have SVG dynamicaly only in JS canvas. Just export it to JS string and
instead of `http://path/to/file.svg`
 supply data uri, which is: `data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding` ... for escaped string use escape() function.

See http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php